# How to render images from code inside a create-react-app project

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

In my app I have some css that has this:

```
background-image: url("../../assets/img/webheader.jpg");
```

And that loads an image from this url:
http://localhost:3000/static/media/webheader.e3104798.jpg

Now, for dev purposes, I want to load that image from code inside a component, and I get the path like this:

```
function getImages() {
    var prefix = process.env.PUBLIC_URL;
    let images = [
         prefix + '/assets/img/webheader.jpg'
    ];
    return images;
}
```

According to this doc https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder , I have to get the prefix from `process.env.PUBLIC_URL;` or by using `%PUBLIC_URL%`.

The former gives me an empty string for the prefix, and the latter gives me this error after rending the img:

```
**URIError: Failed to decode param '/%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/img/webheader.jpg'**
```

Rendering an img HTML element with the values from that array just give me an status code `Status Code: 304 Not Modified`

What could be the problem?

I got asked how I'm using getImages()

I have a component that has a constructor:

```
 class Portafolio extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            images: getImages()
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <NavBar/>
                <div className="container">
                    <GradientImages imageList={this.state.images}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Inside that GradientImages, I render this:

```
let images = this.props.imageList;
    let imagesHtml = images.map((url, index) => (
        <div className="gradient-wrap" key={index}>
            <img src={url} className="img-responsive" alt={'image ' + index}></img>
        </div>
    ));
```

Comment: You posted your code for your `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` attempt but not for your `%PUBLIC_URL%` attempt, correct?  If so you should post the latter.  From the error message, it looks like you used `/%PUBLIC_URL%` instead of `%PUBLIC_URL%`.

Comment: I used `'%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/img/webheader.jpg'`

Comment: Actually where that document says "Inside index.html, you can use it like this..." it seems to be saying that `%PUBLIC_URL%` will only work in index.html.  So you should use `process.env.PUBLIC_URL`, but the mystery is why it's empty for you.  Not sure.

Comment: You can use es6 `import`

Comment: How are you using your getImages?

Comment: @Mordechai I want to have an structure of images grouped by category, and importing them like that doesn't seem like the best approach that it could have

Comment: @zhuber updated question with some code

Answer (score 6):

Both `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` and `%PUBLIC_URL%` are for referring to files in the `public` folder from js and html files respectively. If you want to use an image url which lives in your project files, you can simply import it and use it like this:

```js
import webHeaderImage from '../assets/img/webheader.jpg';

console.log(webHeaderImage); // http://localhost:3000/static/media/webheader.e3104798.jpg

function getImages() {
    let images = [
         webHeaderImage
    ];
    return images;
}
```

When you import an asset like this, [url-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader/) or [file-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/) will take care of it, giving you a URL and copying the file into the output directory.

Answer (score 0):

When using Webpack you need to require images in order for Webpack to process them, which would explain why external images load while internal do not, so instead of

`<img src={'/webheader.jpg'} />`

you need to use

`<img src={require('/webheader.jpg')} />`

replacing `webheader.jpg` with the correct image name for each of them.

That way Webpack is able to process and replace the source image.

Comment: And that will go and look it into the root folder of /public?

Comment: render `<img src={require(url)} className="img-responsive" alt={'image ' + index}></img>`